# Swift Class has another class from Pod with UiViewController and get Nil on outlets because of that

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, cocoapods

First of all, sorry the english.

I have a project in Swift 4.2. One of the Pods is imported and added to a class "Principal View Controller". This Pod has de UIViewController and i cannot add it on the class because it's used on the Pod and Xcode doesn't alow multiple inheritance.

If I remove the Pod from the class the Iboutlets works without problem but the pod is not working ( it's used for side menu ). If i leave the Pod added, the Iboutlets just get nil value.

I track in a debug the code and pass on 2 of the ViewDidLoad and nothing load value on Outlets if Pod is added.

Maybe someone knows the way to fix this?

**I remove some code from classes because it's way more than the 300000 characters that stackoverflow allow...

```
//
//  PrincipalViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import JLSlideMenuController
import Alamofire

class PrincipalViewController: JLSlideNavigationController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewWeather: UIScrollView!
    
    @IBOutlet var profileImage:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var lblUserName:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var menuButton:UIButton!
    var jsonVar:JSON!
    var rutasDisponibles : [Ruta]!
    var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    var viewDayArray = [UIView](repeating: UIView(), count: 7)
    var labelDayArray = [UILabel](repeating: UILabel(), count: 7)
    var labelTempDayArray = [UILabel](repeating: UILabel(), count: 7)
    var ivDayArray = [UIImageView](repeating: UIImageView(), count: 7)
    
    var taskDescargaKmls : URLSessionTask!
    var contador = 1
    
    @IBOutlet weak var btMisRutas: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btRutas: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btInfoMunicipio: UIButton!
    
    var jlSlide: JLSlideNavigationController!
    
    lazy var session : Foundation.URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        config.allowsCellularAccess = false
        let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        return session
    }()
    
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
        profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        let lang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LANG");
        btRutas.setTitle(Languages.translateText("rutas", language: lang!), for: UIControl.State())
        btInfoMunicipio.setTitle(Languages.translateText("info_municipio", language: lang!), for: UIControl.State())
        btMisRutas.setTitle(Languages.translateText("mis_rutas", language: lang!), for: UIControl.State())
        
        if(!OnlineStatus.isConnectedToNetwork()){
            scrollViewWeather.isHidden = true
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func sideMenu(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if menuIsPresented(){
            self.hideMenu(animated: true)
        }
        else{
            self.showMenu(animated: true)
            
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.website.background")
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PrincipalViewController.closeMenu(_:)))
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.parentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        
        addSlideMenu("MenuViewController",storyboardName: "Main",distToTop: 0, widthAspectRatio: 0.8, distToBottom: 0,comeFromLeft: true) 
    }
```

The pod is JSlideMenuController : https://cocoapods.org/pods/JLSlideMenuController

```
//
//  JLSlideMenuViewController.swift
//  Pods
//
//  Created by José Lucas Souza das Chagas on 20/03/16.
//
//

import UIKit

public class JLSlideMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    public var attachedNavController:JLSlideNavigationController!
    
    
    //constraints
    var sideDist:NSLayoutConstraint!
    var distToTopC:NSLayoutConstraint!
    var distToBottomC:NSLayoutConstraint!
    var widthC:NSLayoutConstraint!
    //
    
    /**
     TRUE to enable the menu FALSE to disable
     
     The value of this enable or disable the animations and gestures to show and hide the menu
     */
    public var enabled:Bool = true{
        didSet{
            if enabled == false{
                attachedNavController.hideMenu(animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override public func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.didMove(toParent: parent)
        //print(parent!.childViewControllers)
    }

    //public override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    public func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //override public func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    public func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func removeConstraints(){
        self.view.window!.removeConstraint(sideDist)
        self.view.window!.removeConstraint(distToTopC)
        self.view.window!.removeConstraint(distToBottomC)
        self.view.removeConstraint(widthC)
        
    }
    
    /**
     Call this method to present modally the correct view controller accordingly to some interaction
     with the menu view controller
     
     - parameter VCId: The Id of the view controller to show
     - parameter storyboardName: the name of the storyboard where the view controller is
     - parameter animated: true to transition with some animation or not
     */
    
    public func presentControllerModally(VCId:String,storyboardName:String,animated:Bool){
        let destinyVC = JLSlideNavigationController.loadMenuVC(identifier: VCId, storyboardName: storyboardName)
        
        destinyVC.view.frame = self.attachedNavController.view.frame
       
        self.attachedNavController.hideMenu(animated: false)

        let menuSegue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "actualViewToAnother", source: self.attachedNavController,
            destination: destinyVC, performHandler: { () -> Void in
                
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    // Background Thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // Run UI Updates
                        self.attachedNavController.topViewController!.present(destinyVC, animated: animated, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                /*
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    
                    self.attachedNavController.topViewController!.presentViewController(destinyVC, animated: animated, completion: nil)
                    
                })
                */

        })
        
        //self.prepareForSegue(menuSegue, sender: nil)
        self.attachedNavController.topViewController!.prepare(for: menuSegue, sender: nil)
        
        menuSegue.perform()
    }
    
    /**
     Call this method to show the correct view controller accordingly to some interaction
     with the menu view controller
     
     Use this one if the view controller where the menu is right now have some navigation controller
     
     - parameter VCId: The Id of the view controller to show
     - parameter storyboardName: the name of the storyboard where the view controller is
     - parameter animated: true to transition with some animation or not
     */
    public func showController(VCId:String,storyboardName:String,animated:Bool){
        
        let destinyVC = JLSlideNavigationController.loadMenuVC(identifier: VCId, storyboardName: storyboardName)
        
        destinyVC.view.frame = self.attachedNavController.view.frame
        
        self.attachedNavController.hideMenu(animated: false)

        let menuSegue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "actualViewToAnother", source: self.attachedNavController,
            destination: destinyVC, performHandler: { () -> Void in
                self.attachedNavController.pushViewController(destinyVC, animated: animated)
            })
        
        //self.prepareForSegue(menuSegue, sender: nil)
        self.attachedNavController.prepare(for: menuSegue, sender: nil)

        menuSegue.perform()
        
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

```
//
//  JLSlideNavigationController.swift
//  Pods
//
//  Created by José Lucas Souza das Chagas on 24/04/16.
//
//

import UIKit

open class JLSlideNavigationController: UINavigationController,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    
    /**
     menuVCStoryboardID: The Id of your menu View Controller.
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set) var menuVCStoryboardID:String?
    /**
     the name of the storyboard where your menu View Controller is.
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set) var storyboardName:String?
    /**
     the value of the constraint that indicates the distance between your menu top and this VC top.
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set) var distToTop:CGFloat = 0
    /**
     the value of the constraint that determine your menu Width.
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set)  var width:CGFloat = 250
    /**
     the value of the constraint that indicates the distance between your menu bottom and this VC bottom.
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set) var distToBottom:CGFloat = 0
    /**
     the bolean value that indicates if your menu will come from left or from right of the window.
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set) var comeFromLeft:Bool = true
    /**
     A bolean value that indicates to use or not shadow effects
     */
    @IBInspectable private(set) var useShadowEffects:Bool = false
    
    private var menuContainerView: UIView?
    /**
     The instace of your menu View Controller associated to this View Controller
     */
    private(set) static var myMenuVC:JLSlideMenuViewController?
    
    public static var panGes:UIPanGestureRecognizer?
    
    public static var screeEdgePanGes:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer?

    /**
     Incicates that the pan gesture that were started enabled or not
     */
    
    private var panEnabled:Bool = false
    private var lastPanTouch:CGPoint?
    
    
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        if let pan = JLSlideNavigationController.panGes{
            pan.isEnabled = true
        }
        
        if let pan = JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes{
            pan.isEnabled = true
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if let _ = self.view.window{
            
            checkIfShouldAddOrUpdateMenu()
        }
        print(self.view.window!.gestureRecognizers!.count)
    }
    
   
    
    open override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let pan = JLSlideNavigationController.panGes{
            pan.isEnabled = false
        }
        
        if let pan = JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes{
            pan.isEnabled = false
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    class func loadMenuVC(identifier:String,storyboardName:String)->UIViewController{
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - NavigationController delegate methods
    
    public func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let menuView = menuContainerView , let window = self.view.window{
            window.bringSubviewToFront(menuView)
        }
        let subViews = viewController.view.subviews
        if let screenEdgeGes = JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes{
            for subView in subViews{
                if let gestures = subView.gestureRecognizers{
                    for gesture in gestures{
                        gesture.require(toFail: screenEdgeGes)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
       
    }
    
    //MARK: - Gestures methods
    private func addGestures(){
        //Pan

        if let window = self.view.window , let pan = JLSlideNavigationController.panGes{
            window.removeGestureRecognizer(pan)
        }
        
        JLSlideNavigationController.panGes = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(JLSlideNavigationController.panAction(panGes:)))
        
        self.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(JLSlideNavigationController.panGes!)

        //Screen Edge pan
        if let window = self.view.window , let pan = JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes{
            window.removeGestureRecognizer(pan)
        }
        
        JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(JLSlideNavigationController.screenEdgePanAction(edgePan:)))
        
        if comeFromLeft{
            
            JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes!.edges = UIRectEdge.left

        }
        else{
            JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes!.edges = UIRectEdge.right

        }

        self.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes!)
        
        
        JLSlideNavigationController.panGes!.require(toFail: JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes!)
        
        
        if let screenEdgeGes = JLSlideNavigationController.screeEdgePanGes, let topViewC = topViewController{
            let subViews = topViewC.view.subviews

            for subView in subViews{
                if let gestures = subView.gestureRecognizers{
                    for gesture in gestures{
                        gesture.require(toFail: screenEdgeGes)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    @objc public func screenEdgePanAction(edgePan:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer){
        let currenLocation = edgePan.location(in: self.view)
        
        if let menuView = menuContainerView,  JLSlideNavigationController.myMenuVC!.enabled{
            if edgePan.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began{
                panEnabled = false
                if !menuIsPresented(){
                    panEnabled = true
                    lastPanTouch = currenLocation
                }
                
            }
            else if edgePan.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended{//at the end of pan gesture check if the menu is near to show or hide completelly and then finishes the movement
                panEnabled = false
                let menuFrame = menuView.frame
                if comeFromLeft{
                    if menuFrame.origin.x <= -menuFrame.size.width/2{
                        self.hideMenu(animated: true)
                    }
                    else if menuFrame.origin.x > -menuFrame.size.width/2{
                        self.showMenu(animated: true)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if menuFrame.origin.x >= self.view.frame.width - menuFrame.size.width/2{
                        self.hideMenu(animated: true)
                    }
                    else if menuFrame.origin.x < self.view.frame.width - menuFrame.size.width/2{
                        self.showMenu(animated: true)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
            
            if panEnabled{//if the pan started at a right point continue
                menuView.alpha = 1
                let xDeslocamento = currenLocation.x - lastPanTouch!.x
                
                lastPanTouch = currenLocation
                
                if comeFromLeft{
                    if menuView.frame.origin.x + xDeslocamento >= -menuView.frame.width && menuView.frame.origin.x + xDeslocamento <= 0{
                        
                        menuView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:menuView.frame.origin.x + xDeslocamento ,y:menuView.frame.origin.y)
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if menuView.frame.origin.x + xDeslocamento >= self.view.frame.width - menuView.frame.width  && menuView.frame.origin.x + xDeslocamento <= self.view.frame.width{
                        
                        menuView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:menuView.frame.origin.x + xDeslocamento ,y: menuView.frame.origin.y)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. The custom class in your storyboard needs to be  `PrincipalViewController`. What are you setting it to?

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry, I don't understand Swift very well and less the problem. PrincipalViewController is a class that import the Pod JLSlideMenuController. In Swift 3 works without problem but when update the Pod and the project to Swift 4.2 the outlets from the PrincipalViewController storyboard get nils even after the super.viewDidLoad().
The problem is on self.parentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture) on viewDidLoad() from PrincipalViewController. The parentview is an Outlet and we get a nil error because is not loading. If the JSlide is removed and put UIViewController works.

Comment: But we need the JLSlide to the sidemenu with custom apperance ( it's in too many classes and find another with the same freedom to customize it's an awesome time of work ) . Then, my question is, what is happening exactly to the outlets get nil? I can't add UIVIewController because the Pod has NavigationController and, at the same time, this has the UIViewController...

Comment: In your storyboard you should set the custom class for your scene to `PrincipalViewController`.  How are you creating the view controller instance?  A common problem with outlets being `nil` is creating the view controller directly rather than instantiating it from the storyboard.

Comment: From looking at the documentation you should apply `JSlideNavigationController` as a replacement for `UINavigationController`, not `UIViewController`.